# Max of values from 3 columns in a dataframe?

Tags: python

I would like to calculate the maximum of 3 columns value.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
data = web.DataReader("^NSEI" , data_source="yahoo",start = "1/4/2016",end ="6/4/2018")
data=pd.DataFrame(data)
data["High-Low"] = data["High"]  - data["Low"]
data["Close-low"] = abs(data["Close"].shift(1) - data["Low"])
data["Close-High"] = abs(data["Close"].shift(1) - data["High"])
data["True_Range"] = data[[data["High-Low"], data["Close-low"],data["Close-High"]]].max(axis=1)
```

In `data["True _Range"]` column, I want to take the maximum of value in `data["High-low"]`,`data["Close-low"]` and `data["Close-high"]` columns. On this, it is giving a name error.

```
KeyError: "None of [Index([(156.44970703125, 67.9501953125, 79.75, 118.35009765625, 53.05029296875, 110.75, 100.5, 165.150390625, 161.0, 139.2001953125, 127.25, 98.60009765625, 229.39990234375, 148.7001953125, 105.7998046875, 65.94970703125, 58.19970703125, 59.25, 172.85009765625, 59.2001953125, 148.25, 69.10009765625, 91.099609375, 96.5, 149.349609375, 48.30029296875, 94.10009765625, 248.69970703125, 165.7998046875, 126.0, 166.94970703125, 163.05029296875, 87.25, 80.89990234375, 51.69970703125, 151.0, 81.0498046875, 72.80029296875, 67.7998046875, 268.80029296875, 200.39990234375, 72.2001953125, 77.900390625, 61.7998046875, 85.0, 114.7001953125, 99.7001953125, 83.35009765625, 68.650390625, 92.400390625, 102.85009765625, 105.89990234375, 95.7001953125, 95.849609375, 84.400390625, 56.25, 161.69970703125, 70.64990234375, 98.5, 75.60009765625, 74.0498046875, 60.05029296875, 147.64990234375, 46.89990234375, 94.89990234375, 42.64990234375, 161.94970703125, 54.0498046875, 92.599609375, 77.85009765625, 72.85009765625, 94.35009765625, 50.0, 84.0, 151.9501953125, 50.4501953125, 157.5498046875, 100.349609375, 52.5, 155.10009765625, 51.75, 70.69970703125, 60.5498046875, 120.10009765625, 59.19970703125, 112.2001953125, 66.39990234375, 96.7998046875, 101.75, 60.39990234375, 71.2998046875, 109.400390625, 76.64990234375, 98.39990234375, 45.75, 131.900390625, 134.5, 87.150390625, 49.2001953125, 79.2998046875, ...), (nan, 28.0498046875, 63.44970703125, 184.39990234375, 12.75, 107.0, 76.05029296875, 84.5, 118.60009765625, 109.5, 101.39990234375, 13.14990234375, 193.60009765625, 59.2998046875, 50.80029296875, 1.25, 16.44970703125, 28.14990234375, 21.85009765625, 22.2998046875, 127.900390625, 105.25, 4.150390625, 2.64990234375, 125.89990234375, 112.10009765625, 120.4501953125, 255.75, 107.35009765625, 75.849609375, 125.25, 87.60009765625, 19.39990234375, 45.7998046875, 10.0498046875, 143.849609375, 99.7998046875, 57.30029296875, 14.5, 203.9501953125, 48.05029296875, 85.85009765625, 37.19970703125, 31.5, 43.2001953125, 61.0, 84.39990234375, 25.5498046875, 4.849609375, 85.9501953125, 55.4501953125, 19.35009765625, 5.35009765625, 13.35009765625, 60.4501953125, 44.2998046875, 128.7998046875, 32.85009765625, 46.4501953125, 33.2001953125, 72.2998046875, 8.64990234375, 170.14990234375, 11.4501953125, 78.5, 19.75, 38.35009765625, 8.0498046875, 63.25, 7.7001953125, 37.150390625, 30.64990234375, 38.69970703125, 72.2998046875, 32.5, 22.10009765625, 145.44970703125, 58.5498046875, 72.5, 70.75, 49.75, 0.30029296875, 57.14990234375, 20.099609375, 28.349609375, 106.89990234375, 0.7998046875, 116.19970703125, 42.75, 18.9501953125, 80.0, 103.35009765625, 47.64990234375, 27.5, 15.25, 60.44970703125, 13.60009765625, 7.39990234375, 5.85009765625, 44.2001953125, ...)], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

​

Comment: Try calculating the max of each column separately, then calculating the max of the 3 maxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error signifies that you have input the data instead of the nested columnnames into your view of the dataframe, which produced the error.
Since the data from the columns themselves are not in the columnnames - you received the error.
One way of avoiding the error is:

```
data["True_Range"] = data[["High-Low", "Close-low", "Close-High"]].max(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
data["True_Range"] = data[["High-Low","Close-low","Close-High"]].max(axis=1)
```

Instead of:

```
data["True_Range"] = data[[data["High-Low"], data["Close-low"],data["Close-High"]]].max(axis=1)
```